# Specify a sanitized error when a Meteor check fails

Tags: javascript, meteor

I using [check](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/check) to verify arguments to my meteor methods. I would like to send a helpful error message when the check fails.

Is there a way to specify a sanitized error to send to the client when the check fails?

I could wrap the check in a try/catch block and generate another Meteor error, but this seems needlessly verbose.

Comment: If your method checks ever fail on the server then your client failed to do the right  thing in the first place. In other words, your checks should be the last line of defense, so it feels like you are solving the wrong problem.

Comment: @DavidWeldon That makes sense, but my case is unusual: I'm using meteor style methods as the public API to my project. Clients I may not have written will be calling my methods.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do it I figured so far is to put your check inside of try catch block and then throw new exception with reason/message taken from original one. Not perfect, even ugly, but works for now.

```
try {
  check(param, String)
} catch (ex) {
  let message = ex.message.startsWith('Match error: Match error: ')
    ? ex.message.slice(26, ex.message.length)
    : ex.message

  throw new Meteor.Error(400, message)
}
```